# goapp serveで起動するDataStoreの初期データを用意することはできますか？

Tags: google-app-engine

AppEngine/Go for SDK で　開発サーバーを立ち上げた時
ローカルのDataStoreに初期データを予め用意しておきたいのですが
そういう機能はあるのでしょうか？

オプションに-clear_datastoreはあるので消すことはできそうですが
追加方法はなかったので

Answer (score 0, accepted):

残念ながら、ネイティブの機能では無いと思います。

僕がそのようなことを行いたい時は、初期データ登録用のAPIを作ります。 https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#IsDevAppServer を用いて、Localでしか動かないようにしておきます。
gitで管理している場合だと、init.shを用意しておいて、Setup手順に、まずアプリを動かしてみたいなら、init.shを実行すると書いておくのも良いかもしれませんね。

Answer (score -1):

sinmetalと同じく、自分でダミーデータ等登録する一式用意してます。
modulesで別モジュールとしてdev用の下処理まとめておいて、
Modelに対応するCSVファイル見つかったら放り込んでます。